# What are the reasons to convert string date to a long when inserting a date into sqllite?

Tags: java, android, performance, sqlite, long-integer

I have seen many programs in java (android programs in particular) that convert string dates to longs and also save the date to an sqlite database.  Why is this necessary?  Is it doing a conversion? Or is there something in particular about sqlite that requires this? When coding mobile applications CPU work should be kept to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases do not store dates as strings.  Think about this for a second the text "July 20, 2013" takes 13 bytes.  How many bits is that?  13 * 8 = 104.  Instead the internal representation is some variation of an offset from a known time.  In C this is the epoch.  The number of days since 1970 can be stored in a 16 bit number for example.  The reason for the conversion is to change the representation into a compact form so that the database can operate effectively with the data.

Comment: And also to solve the timezone problem, and also so a variety of formats can be applied when it is displayed, and, ...